# NSDateFormatter with invalid dates

Tags: date, nsdateformatter

I've just found a strange issue.
I've tried to parse an invalid date like `1999-02-31 23:30:00` using `NSDateFormatter`.

```
var str = "1999-02-31 23:30:00"
var f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
f.locale = Locale(identifier: "it")
//  f.calendar = Calendar.current
f.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Rome")!
let parsedDate = f.date(from: str)
```

The result is `nil` if you parse it without setting the calendar; once you set it the result is the the date adjusted to the extra day added to the wrong date (March 3, 1999).

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've found `isLenient` property.
Once set the formatter will use heuristics to guess at the date which is intended by the string. As with any guessing, it may get the result date wrong (that is, a date other than that which was intended).